# Sidekiq Delayed Mailer with variable method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, sidekiq

Just for some context:
I have 3 different methods called welcome_email(user_id), banned_email(user_id) and upgrade_email((user_id) in a file called `notification_mailer.rb`.

Is there a way where I can call the different methods differently based on a string? (aka a string variable as part of a method call).

For example:
I know I can do

> NotificationMailer.send("#{email_type}_email", user.id)

to call

> NotificationMailer.welcome_email(user.id) / NotificationMailer.banned_email(user.id) /
>   NotificationMailer.upgrade_email(user.id)

but how do I call (adding in the delay part)

> Notification.delay.welcome_email(user.id) ?

Can I just do `NotificationMailer.delay.send("#{email_type}_email", user.id)`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a NotificationMailer object that's an ActionMailer with a variety of different notification methods that each take a user, you can write a simple Sidekiq job to send your e-mails in the background:

```
class NotificationWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(notification_type, user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    NotificationMailer.send(notification_type, user).deliver
  end
end
```

Now that you have this, you can enqueue an async notification e-mail by calling that job:

```
NotificationWorker.perform_async('welcome_email', user.id)
```